# TS 2322 - Property 'id' is missing in type '{ id: number

Tags: typescript

New to Angular and TS. I created model with the same properties but i got error and cant find solution:

> TS2322: Type '{ id: number; model: string; plate: string;
>   deliveryDate: string; deadline: string; client: { fir...' is not
>   assignable to type 'Car'. Property 'id' is missing in type '{ id:
>   number; model: string; plate: string; deliveryDate: string; deadline:
>   string; client: { fir...'.    cars : Car = [

my files:

```
//cars-list.component.ts

import { Car } from '../models/car';
.
.
.
cars : Car = [
{
  id: 1,
  model: 'Mazda Rx7',
  plate: 'GD2121E',
  deliveryDate: '21-04-2017',
  deadline: '05-05-2016',
  client: {
    firstName: 'Jan',
    surname: 'Kowalski'
  },
  cost: 300,
  isFullyDamaged: true
}, 
...
```

and

```
//car.ts
import {Client} from './client';
export interface Car {
  id: number;
  model: string;
  plate: string;
  deliveryDate: string;
  deadline: string;
  client: Client;
  cost: number;
  isFullyDamaged: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to assign an array of objects to a variable of type Car. Make the variable an array of Cars.

```
cars : Car[] = [
{
  id: 1,
  model: 'Mazda Rx7',
  plate: 'GD2121E',
  deliveryDate: '21-04-2017',
  deadline: '05-05-2016',
  client: {
    firstName: 'Jan',
    surname: 'Kowalski'
  },
  cost: 300,
  isFullyDamaged: true
}, 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who used like me:

```
var myObject = objects.filter(o => o.id === id)
```

Replace it by find() to return an object and not an array:

```
var myObject = objects.find(o => o.id === id)
```